# What does it mean to have "RFC-compliant" code?

Tags: python, rfc

I have heard the term RFC-compliant code in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3R4gP6Egh5M) at minute 1:00. What exactly does it mean?

Comment: A very quick search [turned up this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RFCs).  For example, the [HTTP RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1945).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments Usually refers to RFCs that define the formal specifications of internet protocols. For example, here's the definition of a uri template in an rfc https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6570

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RFC-compliant code is code that follows the formal requirements for the protocols in the TCP/IP stack as specified in a number of RFC ([*"request for comments"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments)) documents published by the Internet Engineering Task Force, aka the IETF. There are many different types of RFC-Compliant requirements, such as [HTTP RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945), [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822.html), [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045.html), [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.html), [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047.html), and [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231.html). A complete list of these RFCs can be found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RFCs).

Since you requested an example, lets take a look at [this Github repository file](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/pyoauth/blob/master/pyoauth/oauth1/protocol.py) that builds an OAuth implementation for clients and servers. Specifically, the `generate_nonce` function. (To avoid copyright / licensing issues, the function will not be posted as part of this answer. Please click the link above to view the file).

Looking at the docstring of `generate_nonce`, the function "generates a random ASCII-encoded unsigned integral number in decimal representation". Then it shows the specific RFC guideline it's following: [RFC 5849 - Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.3). So this function is an example of a piece of code that is RFC Compliant, specifically RFC 5849 Compliant.

Comment: can you state an example?